# Prove a compact Hausdorff space with a group structure is a topological group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Here is an exercise from the textbook of topology by Armstrong.

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff space which has the structure of a group. Show that $G$ is a topological group if the multiplication function $m:G\times G \rightarrow G$ is continuous.

I tried to use the conditions to prove the inverse function is also continuous, but I couldn't find out how to connect the inverse with the multiplication...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is there to prove?   Isn't that the definition of a topological group?

Comment: @WilliamElliot No, one needs to know inversion is also continuous.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the map $(a,b)\to (a,ab)$. Prove that it's a homeomorphism from
$G\times G$ to $G\times G$ and consider its inverse.

Answer (score 2):

This has an elegant proof using universal nets (or ultrafilters, or [convergence of maps with respect to ultrafilters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568548/where-has-this-common-generalization-of-nets-and-filters-been-written-down) which would be my favorite way to do it).   To show the inverse map is continuous, it suffices to show it preserves convergence of universal nets.  So suppose $(g_i)$ is a universal net converging to some $g\in G$.  The net $(g_i^{-1})$ is then also a universal net, and so since $G$ is compact it must converge to some $h\in G$.  Now the net $(g_i,g_i^{-1})$ converges to $(g,h)$ in $G\times G$, so by continuity of $m$, $(g_ig_i^{-1})$ must converge to $gh$.  But $g_ig_i^{-1}=1$ for all $i$, and so since $G$ is Hausdorff this constant net can only converge to $1$.  Thus $gh=1$, and $h=g^{-1}$.  That is, $(g_i^{-1})$ converges to $g^{-1}$, as desired.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $Y$ is compact and $f:X\to Y$ is a map whose graph is closed in $X\times Y$, then $f$ is continuous.  In this case, the graph of the inverse map is closed in $G\times G$ since it is $m^{-1}(\{1\})$.

Comment: I wrote down the closed graph implies continuous argument in another way (not using nets) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2488375/4280) yesterday.